# Android 2.3+: Secure chat program from F-droid

Tags: android, chat, encryption

I am looking for a secure chat program that:

- Works on Android 2.3+
- Is available in F-droid or as APK (Available on Google Play is not enough)
- Is compatible between versions
- Is under a free (as freedom) license
- Is as easy to setup as RedPhone (but it is even better if it does not require a phone number, as it will only be used over wifi)

*Why not TextSecure?* I hear you ask. Because the only APK for Android 2.3 I have found (http://www.appsapk.com/textsecure-private-sms-mms/) is incompatible with newer versions of TextSecure.

If you point to an APK and not an app on F-droid, please also link to the license, so it is clear that is is under a free (as freedom) license.

Answer (score 1):

I installed [Chatsecure](https://chatsecure.org/). Man, that is good!

- Works on Android 2.3: Yes
- Requires Google Play: No
- Compatible between the versions I tested.
- License: https://chatsecure.org/about/ (GPLv3+/iPhone) (Apache/Android)
- Ease of setup: Easier than RedPhone, you do not need a SIM-card. Just create a new account by entering desired username and password.

Bonus points for:

- Facebook chat account. So you can chat with your Facebook friends (and maybe convince them to install ChatSecure, so you can talk encrypted without Facebook listening in).
- Verification of keys is well done.
- It works over Tor if you have OrBot installed.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to ChatSecure (answered above) you might investigate [Xabber](http://www.xabber.com/). The current version requires Android 4.0 and is available on F-droid. The software is open source and license is GPLv3. It's also available as APK from the F-droid [site](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.xabber.androiddev).

The older version, Xabber Classic, runs on Android 2.3 and is supposed to be "coming soon" to F-droid.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! This post does not contain enough information to be considered a quality answer. Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer, otherwise it might be removed. We are not an "extension to Google": answers must explicitly point out how requirements are met, and what makes the product(s) recommendable.